Как работать с @uiw/react-codemirror codemirror
Есть вот такой код, думаю и так понятно, что и зачем тут, но мне ничего не понятно. Суть в том, что я не могу поменять язык на котором будет компилироваться codemirror, я пробовал через extensions={[cpp()/java()/go()]}, options ={{metod = 'java/go/cpp'}} через langs пробовал тоже. Ничего не помогает компилятор всегда работает на javascript, даже если я удалю extensions или options он продолжит компилить на js. Помогите пж. Заранее спасибо!


import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import { cpp } from "@codemirror/lang-cpp";
function CodeEditor() {
    const [code, setCode] = useState('');
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');


    const handleCodeChange = (newCode) => {
        setCode(newCode);
    };

    const handleExecuteCode = () => {
        try {
            const result = eval(code);
            setResult(result);
        } catch (error) {
            setResult('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>

                <CodeMirror
                    height="500px"
                    onChange={handleCodeChange}
                    extensions={[cpp()]}
                />
                <button onClick={handleExecuteCode}>Execute</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Compiled Code:</h3>
                <h1>{result}</h1>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}



